# Decrease the relevancy/weight of a particular Managed Property in Fast Search

Tags: fast-for-sharepoint

I have crawled a external database using jdbcconnector of Fast Search. Along with this there are certain other content sources also there. I want the result of the external database should be at the bottom in the results.

For this I have also the decrease the priority of managed property. I have also applied  negative boost the managed property using powershell but it is still showing the results at the top.

How to make the results from an external database show at the bottom in search results?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you add two Search Results web parts. The top one would only show results from the other content sources, and exclude the external database. The bottom one would only show results from the external database?

Comment: Hi, 
We are using fast search for crawling ektron(CMS) database and another database and consuming search asmx service to show the results on our site search using FQL. I have defined two content source there one for ektron cms database and other for another database in FQL and i want the result of another database should be at the lower in the search results.